# Set grantUriPermissions to false

Tags: android, android-fileprovider

When I performed a static scan on the Android app’s codebase using Fluid Attacks, I got an "Unauthorized access to files - APK Content Provider" vulnerability. To fix that, I have to set
`android:grantUriPermissions="false"` of the File Provider.

When I set that attribute to false, the app crashes and gives me this log message `Unable to get provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider: java.lang.SecurityException: Provider must grant uri permissions`

As recommended [here](https://docs.fluidattacks.com/criteria/vulnerabilities/075/#recommendation), I see that I should use element `grant-uri-permission` within the provider element. Does anyone know how to use the `grant-uri-permission` element?

**
My Provider element**

```
<provider
    android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="false">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/filepaths" />
</provider>
```

**My file paths file **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<paths>
    <external-files-path name="camera_files" path="Pictures"/>
    <files-path path="download/" name="download" />
</paths>
```